# Does react have a "null element"?

Tags: reactjs

I have a piece of a component that looks like this

```
            c.props.results.totalCount > c.props.searchOptions.perPage 
                ? createElement(ReactPaginate, {
                    previousLabel: "<",
                    nextLabel: ">",
                    pageNum: Math.ceil(c.props.results.totalCount / c.props.searchOptions.perPage),
                    marginPagesDisplayed: 2,
                    pageRaneDisplayed: 5,
                    containerClassName: "pagination",
                    activeClass: "active",
                    forceSelected: c.props.searchOptions.page,
                    clickCallback: noop
                })
                : null
```

Basically, if there is anything to page, include a pager widget, otherwise don't.

I'd like to encapsulate this logic in its own component.

```
createElement(OptionalPager, c.props)
```

The only problem is that the render function can't return `null` and I'd prefer not to insert an intermediate element here. Is there some sort of `React.DOM.null` element that I can return instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The render function for your class should be able to accept null.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html

If you are calling React.render yourself though you can render noscript just like they do

```
React.render(<noscript />, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If in rendering you can specify no rendering as an empty string '', along the lines of:

```
{(stat == "SHOW_BUTTON") ? <button onClick={ this.myAction. bind(this,i,item) }>buttonLabel</button> : '' }
```